# Is there an idiom suggesting the following fact: The name of the book belies the theme in it.

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases, expressions

> E.g.: I answer a question on ELU based on the subject line, however, I realise later that the body of the question provide a different input altogether.

- The name of the book belies the theme in it.  E.g. The title of the book hints of Mystery but the story revolves around family drama.

Is there an idiom suggesting the above fact?

Requested: Idiom/ phrases/one-word

Comment: ***Don't judge a book by its title.***

Comment: The usual idiom used in American English when you want to speak about a deliberate deception of that sort is **bait and switch**.

Comment: @DanBron - isn't it ***Don't judge a book by the cover***?

Comment: @Josh61 Yes, that was the joke, you see.

Comment: I think it's ***"you can't judge a book by its cover"***.

Comment: Why not just characterize such a book as *deceptively titled?*

Comment: [*Never trust a title*](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/NeverTrustATitle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would call the title **misleading**. If it is purposely misleading to add impact (e.g. the book is titled as a teen romance, but becomes a murder mystery), I would call it **diversionary** or a **smokescreen**.

As those commenting have suggested, **don't judge a book by it's cover** is a popular idiom, though it would serve better as a warning to be wary of this kind of title, rather than a description of the title itself.

Comment: +1.. IMO....Judging a book by its cover is being superficial, judgmental, narrowminded.......

Comment: Thanks, when I wrote "•The name of the book belies the theme in it", I meant The cover of the book.......